# How do I access the ASP.NET Configuration Tool when a site is live? This is ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, configuration

I was wondering if it's possible to access the ASP.NET Configuration Tool once a site is live.  To be able to create and edit users and roles is obviously very important, and from what I've been reading, once a site is deployed, the Configuration Tool is no longer accessible.  If this is the case, HOW do I add users, etc.?

By the way, I found a User Management plugin which brings a lot of the Configuration Tool's capabilities to the front end of a User Management section of the deployed website, but it DOES NOT offer the capability to add a new user.  Help??? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That all depends.  If by "going live" you mean "Publishing the website and the database to a different computer through which you cannot access the database any longer", then yes.  If you still have sql access (ie. you can run SQL Management Studio from your dev machien) the no you can access it by changing your web.config.

Alternatively, you can install Visual Studio express on your remote server and be able to access it from there.

Answer (score 0):

The ASP.NET Configuration Tool GUI is not available once the site is live unless you have access to the database from your development machine.

All of the settings for user authentication can be modified via your web.config file.

You can add/edit users and roles via the Membership and Roles class in the System.Web.Security namespace.

Answer (score 0):

1: Website admin tool is accessible via Visual Studio only.

2: You can access your membership database on live via WSAT by changing connectionstring in your web.config to point to your live membership db.

Apart from using WSAT, asp.net has CreateUser control which you can use to create user on live. This is the same control used by WSAT.

These links should help:

[CreateUserWizard](http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/login/createuserwizard.aspx)

[Custom WSAT Tool](https://web.archive.org/web/20210306174425/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/052307-1.aspx)

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/18/427754.aspx